# Uniqueness of Caratheodory Extension

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, outer-measure

I am trying to prove the following:

Given a pre-measure $p : R \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ where $R \subset 2^X$ is a set-ring, define the outer measure $u^{\ast}(E) = \inf\{\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} p(A_j) : E \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j \}$ where $\inf\emptyset = +\infty$. Define the Caratheodory measurable sets as usual: $C = \{A \in 2^X : \forall B \in 2^X : u^{\ast}(B) = u^{\ast} ( B\cap A) + u^{\ast}(B \setminus A) \}$. Then $(X,C,u^{\ast})$ is a measure space, $R \subset C$, and $u^{\ast}$ restricts to $p$ on $R$. Show that if $\lambda$ is a measure on $C$ restricting to $p$ on $R$, and there exist an increasing sequence of sets in $R$, $\{X_n\}$ such that $u^{\ast}(X_n) = \lambda(X_n) < + \infty$, with $X_n \uparrow X$, and we already know that $\lambda(E) \leq u^{\ast}(E)$ for any $E \in C$ then $u^{\ast}(E) = \lambda(E)$ for any $E \in C$.

My attempt:

It suffices to show that $u^{\ast}(E \cap X_n) = \lambda(E \cap X_n)$ for any $X_n$ in the increasing sequence. Since both $u^{\ast}(E)$ and $\lambda(E)$ are the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ of these terms.

Since $E \in C$, by definition we have $u^{\ast}(X_n) = u^{\ast}(X_n \cap E) + u^{\ast}(X_n \setminus E) $. Moreover we have that $u^{\ast}(X_n) = \lambda(X_n)$ since $X_n \in R$, and since $\lambda$ is a measure and thus finitely additive, $\lambda(X_n) = \lambda(X_n \cap E) + \lambda(X_n \setminus E)$, which gives $$u^{\ast}(X_n \cap E) + u^{\ast}(X_n \setminus E) = \lambda(X_n \cap E) + \lambda(X_n \setminus E)$$ We have that $\lambda(X_n \cap E) \leq u^{\ast}(X_n \cap E)$ and $\lambda(X_n \setminus E) \leq u^{\ast}(X_n \setminus E)$ since we know that $\lambda \leq u^{\ast}$ on $C$. Since each term in the previous two inequalities are necessarily finite, this implies that $\lambda(X_n \cap E) = u^{\ast}(X_n \cap E)$ and $\lambda(X_n \setminus E) = u^{\ast}(X_n \setminus E)$ , giving the desired result.

Is this proof sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathscr{E}$ is a semiring and $\mu$ is a nonnegative $\sigma$-additive
and $\sigma$-subadditive function on $\mathscr{E}$, i.e.

1. $\mu(\bigcup_n A_n)=\sum_n\mu(A_n)$ whenever $\{A_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset\mathscr{E}$ is a pariwise disjoint sequence and $\bigcup_n A_n\in\mathscr{E}$, and
2. $\mu(\bigcup_nA_n)\leq \sum_n\mu(A_n)$ whenever $\{A_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset\mathscr{E}$ and $\bigcup_nA_n\in\mathscr{E}$,

then the extension $\mu$ to all of $\sigma(\mathscr{E})$ may not be unique. However, the Caratheodory construction provides a maximal extension, that is, if $\mu$ is the measure built using the procedure of Caratheodory, and $\nu$ is any other extension of $\mu$ to $\sigma(\mathscr{E}$, then
$$ \nu(E)\leq\mu(E),\quad\forall E\in\sigma(\mathscr{E})$$

When $\mathscr{E}$ is a ring, then the extension is unique.

---

Here is a sketch of the proof:

Let $\eta$ be another extension of $\mu$ to $(\Omega,\sigma(\mathscr{E}))$. For any $E\in\sigma(\mathscr{E})$, choose $B_n\in\mathscr{E}$ so that $E\subset\bigcup_nB_n=B$. Then $\eta(E)\leq\eta(B)\leq\sum_n\eta(B_n)=\sum_n\mu(B_n)$. Taking infima over all possible covers gives  $\eta(E)\leq\mu^*(E)=\mu(E)$.

Assume that  $\mathscr{E}$ is a ring and suppose that
$E\in\sigma(\mathscr{E})$ with $\mu^*(E)=\mu(E)<\infty$. For any
$\varepsilon>0$ choose $B_n\in\mathscr{E}$ so that
$E\subset\bigcup_nB_n=B$ and $\mu(B)<\mu(E)+\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Hence,
$\mu(B\setminus E)<\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Since
$A_k:=\bigcup^k_{j=1}B_j\nearrow B$, we can choose $k$ so that
$\mu(B)-\mu(A_k)=\mu(B\setminus A_k)<\tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Since
$\eta(B)=\eta(E)+\eta(B\setminus E)$, $\eta\leq \mu$ and $\eta=\mu$ on
$\mathscr{E}$, it follows that
$$
\begin{align}
\eta(E)&=\eta(B)-\eta(B\setminus E)\geq\eta(A_k)-\eta(B\setminus E)\\
&\geq\mu(A_k)-\mu(B\setminus E)> \mu(B)-\varepsilon\geq\mu(E)-\varepsilon
\end{align}
$$
Letting $\varepsilon\searrow0$ we obtain that $\eta(E)=\mu(E)$.

This is also related to the maximality of the Daniell mean of the elementary integral $(\mathcal{E},I)$ where $\mathcal{E}$ is the space of bounded simple functions $\phi=\sum^n_{k=1}\mathbb{1}_{A_k}$ such that $|I(\phi)|=|\sum^n_{k=1}a_k\mu(A_n)|<\infty$.

---

Some references:

- Kallenberg's Foundations of probability chapter 1 has an excellent exposition of the Caratheodory construction starting from semi rings.
- Klaus Bichteler's Integration Theory: A functional approach, has an excellent presentation of the Daniell integral and is equivalence to the Lebesgue-Caratheodory construction. The book discusses the maximality that I mention above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and references. I have seen the proof you give and I think you implicitly use sigma finiteness (maybe you shoukd add this to your answer) but do not mention it. I would like to know if the proof I give is sound so if you add that to your answer I will accept it, I think the proof you present and my proof achieve the same goals.

Comment: For rings the proof is pretty standard and your follows more or less what I have seen in many textbooks. I wrote my solution to emphasize the the extensión has the particular characteristic of having a maximal property.  Granted, your initial pseudo metric is defined on a ring in which uniqueness holds, but that leaves out many important examples, the Lebesgue measure on the real line for instance, which  start  semi ring of right closed intervals. The extensión here is no unique but it is maximal. This has a great deal of implications, which are beyond the scope of the OP.